# Generic without type as method parameter - can't resolve it's field type

Tags: java, generics

Let's consider a class:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

that I'm passing as a parameter to a method.

---

I have a problem understanding why here the type `String` isn't resolved:

```
public void test(Foo t) {
    t.list.get(0).contains("test");
}
```

and the `t.list` is treated as `List<Object>` while here everything works just fine:

```
public void test(Foo<?> t) {
    t.list.get(0).contains("test");
}
```

and `t.list` is `List<String>`.

---

The other questions about Type Erasure that have been linked, approach the problem from a different angle. Without knowing the answer to my own question I failed to see the connection and it is why I do not think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Murat has answered your question, but you are aware that the `<T>` in `Foo<T>` is redundant, right?

Comment: @Michael yes, it was just for the purpose of giving an example where the `T` isn't used for the actual field type.

Comment: @Oleksandr in fact both questions are about the same problem but approach it from a different angle. Facing my problem and not knowing the solution I would be unable to understand the underlying reason behind both.

Comment: @Jakubs The solution is very simple - don't use raw types ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `Foo t`, `t` is a [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) so its non-static, non-inherited members, like the `list` in above code, are also raw types. Here the relevant part of the Java Language Specification (see above link):

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.
>
> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - . . .
> - A non-static member type of a raw type R that is not inherited from a superclass or superinterface of R.

and/or

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or **non-static field** (§8.3) of a raw type C that is **not inherited** from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the **raw type** that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Just declare the `list` as `static` and it will be interpreted as a `List` of `String` as expected <sub>(**for testing**)</sub>.

On the other side, the declaration `Foo<?>` is not a raw type and consequently the `list` is also not considered a raw type.

An [advice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-500) later on that page:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

<sup>Note: Type Erasure and generated byte-code is the same in both cases...</sup>

Answer (score 6):

That's how [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) works.

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Since your method accepts a raw type, the compiler applies the type erasure by erasing the type `String` and replace it with `Object`. That's why `contains` is not recognized since `Object` does not have that method call.

By supplying `<?>` you provide a bounded type and that will be used for the type erasure. There the compiler will recognize `contains` since `String` has it.